# Why is $\infty - \infty$ Not $0$?

Tags: infinity

∞ - 2(∞/2)

There are more advanced questions on here but I often get caught up on nuances in the "basics".

It seems important to clear these things up before moving on.

Comment: Since $\infty$ is not a number.

Comment: Perhaps, it would help to know what type of arithmetic is allowed if you choose to work with infinity in your number system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102813/is-infty-undefined/3102868#3102868.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the result of $\infty - \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infty-infty)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to evaluate $\infty-\infty$. This is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), one of several operations using $+,\,-,\,\times,\,\div$ on two extended real numbers (of which $\infty$ is an example) that can't be defined. In particular, functions $f,\,g$ can satisfy $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\infty$ with just about any behaviour for $\lim_{x\to0}(f(x)-g(x))$. You can get $\infty$ from $f=\frac{2}{x^2},\,g=\frac{1}{x^2}$, $-\infty$ if you exchange these, $0$ if you use either function twice, your favourite real number if you then add it to $f$, or none of these behaviours if you add $\sin x$ to $f$ instead.