# mathematical operations with infinity

Tags: infinity

I suppose these are the equations with infinity that are universally considered correct:

1. ∞ = ∞
2. ∞ + *n* = ∞
3. ∞ * *n* = ∞
4. *n*/∞ = 0

Where *n* can be any possible value.

These equations can be rearranged to give the following results:

1. ∞ - ∞ = 0
2. ∞ - ∞ = *n*
3. ∞ / ∞ = *n*
4. ∞ * 0 = *n*

Where *n* can be any possible value.

But can *n* also be infinite?

If so the following final derivations can be made(in no particular order):

1. ∞ + ∞ = ∞
2. ∞ - ∞ = *n*        (where -∞ <= *n* <= ∞)
3. ∞ * ∞ = ∞
4. ∞ / ∞ = *n*        (where -∞ <= *n* <= ∞)

Are these statements valid? Also the interesting thing here is that in the final equations, 1. and 3. both have a single value of infinity whereas 2. and 4. Can have any possible value, including -∞, 0 and ∞. Does that mean 1. and 3. are not undefined?

Comment: "But the question is, can $n$ also be infinite?" Yes, $2n-n=n$ and $n\to\infty$ gives $\infty-\infty=\infty$ in your way of thinking.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968262/infty-infty-well-defined-with-sup-and-inf/3968278#3968278)

Comment: I had another question though. it seems like ∞−∞ results in ∞, but it can also be 0 or any other value. I suppose this is why ∞ - ∞ is considered undefined as it may result in many possible values. but ∞ + ∞ always gives one value, that is ∞. So does that mean ∞ + ∞ is not undefined and can be considered to be ∞ in all cases?

Comment: Treating $\infty$ as a number (with which we can do the usual manipulations) leads inevitably to contradictions. Such equations should be considered as thumb-rules how to deal with limits. In this sense (and only this sense) , we can say , for example $\infty+\infty=\infty$ , but $\infty-\infty$ cannot be defined even in this sense because we cannot conclude the limit.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102813/is-infty-undefined/3102868#3102868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us follow the convention that an expression with $\infty$ is "defined" (in the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)) if: when you replace each $\infty$ with any function/sequence whose limit is $\infty$, and each real number with any function/sequence with that limit, the limit of the entire expression is always the same real number or divergence to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Then you are right that $\infty+\infty$ and $\infty*\infty$ are defined and equal $\infty$. And you are right that $\infty-\infty$ and $\infty/\infty$ (and $0*\infty$) are undefined. (If you need proofs for these and can't find them elsewhere, let me know.)

Because of this, it is wrong to write something like "$\infty-\infty=n$ where $n$ is any number", because $\infty-\infty$ is undefined. It's not equal to anything. And we don't usually use the equals sign in a way that would allow multiple values at once.

> But can *n* also be infinite?

I will interpret this as "are there functions where $\infty-\infty$, $\infty/\infty$ and $\infty*0$ correspond to limits that diverge to infinity?"
Yes. For examples: ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(2n)-(n)=\infty$, ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(n^2)/(n)=\infty$, and ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(n^2)*(1/n)=\infty$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. however I had one question, in your final sentence don't the examples reduce to ∞-∞ and ∞/∞ which are undefined because they result in many possible values and so don't always diverge to ∞ ?

Comment: @Neelim It depends what you mean by "*they* result in many possible values". "$\infty-\infty$" is undefined because, for instance, "${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(n+17)-(n)=17$ and ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(n)-(n^2)=-\infty$". But the particular limit ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(2n)-(n)$ has just one extended real value: $\infty$.

Comment: it seems to me like $lim n→∞ (2n)−(n) = 2∞ - ∞ = ∞ - ∞ $ which is undefined and not just one value i.e. ∞

Comment: @Neelim That is incorrect. You can't always replace $n$s by $\infty$s. ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}(2n)-(n)={\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}n=\infty$. But you can only replace the $n$s with $\infty$ ***if*** you're not in an undefined case like $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: oh I see, so the expressions with n are reduced first and then replaced with ∞

Comment: @Neelim Yes. In simple calculations, that is straightforward and works fine. In more complicated cases like ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}n+2-\sqrt{n^2+3n+1}=1/2$, you need to know Calculus or just the right algebra trick to try.